# Cocoa sizeof(string) always returns 8

Tags: cocoa

I have a few lines of code that cut off the first 6 characters of a string that will contain a directory path. If the directory path stored in sourcePathString is "file:///Users/username/Desktop" then shouldn't this code set subString to "/Users/username/Desktop"? For some reason it will instead be set to "/Users/u", which means that stringSize is getting set to 8. This happens no matter how long the directory path is.

```
NSString *sourcePathString = [sourceURL absoluteString];
int stringSize = sizeof(sourcePathString);
NSString *subString = [sourcePathString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(7,stringSize)];
```

I know that the string sourcePathString contains the whole directory path, because I have tried putting its contents straight into a textfield.

I am very new to Cocoa so it is very possible that I've missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case `sizeof()` will return the size of the pointer pointing to the object `string`. on a 64-bit system this is 8 bytes.

you want to use `int stringSize = [string length]`

or more specific: you mud adjust the it for the `NSRangeCall`

```
NSString *subString = [sourcePathString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(7,[string length] - 8)];
```

as it doesn't start at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have fixed my first problem, but now I am getting this -[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {7, 69} out of bounds; string length 69